# Retrofitting drip edges with a wooden spacer?

Tags: water, roofing, gutters

I'm preparing to install gutters, but I've noticed that rain just flows down my fascia boards.  I anticipate having a problem with water going behind the gutters.  I saw [this Q&A](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18701/how-can-i-prevent-water-from-getting-behind-the-gutter), but the solution I'm considering isn't mentioned there.

[This site](http://www.custom-carpentry.net/jobs/wooden-gutters/drip-edge-failure.html) argues that there's supposed to be a wooden strip behind the metal drip edge, to force the water to fall from the corner instead of flowing down the fascia.  This makes perfect sense to me, but at the same time, I'm a little skeptical because this is the only mention of it I've found.  (The reason nobody does this, they say, is because roofers don't do carpentry.)

[image: cross section showing wooden drip]

So my question is, would it be a good idea to try to retrofit my roof with these wooden drips?  If so, is there any reason I shouldn't reuse the existing metal drip edge?

Comment: Since this 4 year old question got bumped, i am wondering how those WOOD gutters are holding up?

Comment: @AlaskaMan The gutters aren't wood; the image was just for illustrating the drip edge overhang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely do not want water running down the fascia board. The drip edge is suppose to run the water away from the fascia - wind can kick some water back onto the fascia but most water should be diverted away with the drip edge.

If the drip edge is installed correctly (over edge by about 0.5", under felt on the eaves and over felt on the rakes), you could try to get a thin piece of material between the drip edge and fascia to provide the spacing needed (you want about a fingers width). If you do that, be careful that the material you use does not wick water up behind the fascia (so make sure that the spacer isn't too close to the bottom of the drip edge).

Comment: Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.